# applicationDidEnterBackground is called twice on iOS7

Tags: ios7, appdelegate

it's about iOS application on iOS7.
when an active application be killed from the multitasking display, I realized it seems like the appDelegate method "applicationDidEnterBackground" is called twice.
 if anyone already know about it,please me let know the reason why it happens. (is it the iOS7 bug or spec??)

Comment: strage,why I just call once？

Comment: the method is called only once by pushing a home button, but when you terminate the ACTIVE app from the MULTITASKING DISPLAY, the method is called once again. i think it's an iOS7 bug as kid0 said.

Comment: This happens in my app also. I can see no good reason for this being called twice. Guess we just need to ensure that the method is idempotent, this kind of method should naturally be so anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my testing also shows that applicationDidEnterBackground is called twice when the app is terminated. even the comments in the default template state that this should only happen upon termination if the app supports background execution (which the app I tested does not), and i guess one call is sufficient. probably a bug, not the first in iOS 7

Comment: thx :) i'm gonna use the another delegate method "applicationWillResignActive" instead. seems like it works fine.

Comment: I can confirm this. My app its state machine crashes explicitly when it gets unexpected input. Lo and behold, I see these crashes appearing in the field via Crashlytics :)